# Set defined for proving existence of $ r > 0 $ s.t. $ r^2 = 2 $ is problematic

Tags: real-analysis

Theorem: There exists a positive real number $ r $ s.t. $ r^2 = 2 $

The proof in my book begins with defining a set $ L = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} | x \geq 0 , x^2 \leq 2 \} $  and then proceeds to show that $ r^2 = 2 $ is the maximum of this set. However, I don't understand the following:
Since the set L contains real numbers $ x $ such that $x \geq 0, x^2 \leq 2 $, then specifically, it contains a number $ x>0 $ s.t. $ x^2 = 2 $ . How am I supposed to show the existence of such a number ( $ r^2 = 2 $ ) if it already exists  in the set I've defined? ( In which case, the set $ L $ is problematic since it already contains the number which I need to prove exists )

Comment: How do you know that it exists in the set?

Comment: The set is defined as such. Are you saying that I am defining the set to show that indeed such a number exists ( from the set's properties )?

Comment: yup, you got it now

Comment: You are assuming you what you are trying to prove.  How do you know that there exists a number that when squared is equal to $2$.  If such a number *does* exist and is in your set, that's fine.  But why would you think so number does exist?  Every number I pick at random doesn't equal to $2$ when squared so why should I assume such a number exists.

Comment: Suppose I asked you to prove there exists a least positive (strictly larger than $0$) and gave you the set $L = \{x \in \mathbb R|x\ge 0; x > 0\}$ and you pointed out that as it contains *all* positive numbers it specifically contains the number you've been tasked to find.

Comment: Yes you are right, I over-thinked about this. As stated by @Rob_Arthan below, there exists a set such as $ L = \{x \in \Bbb{R} \mid x \ge 0, x^2 \le 2\} $ , regardless if there is or isn't a number in it such that $ r^2 =2 $  ( because the set is not empty ), so there is no problem with defining such a set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that you know there exists some $x$ such that $x \ge 0$ and $x^2 \le 2$, (e.g., $1$) and you know that for all large enough $x$, $x^2 > 2$ (e.g., that is true for $x \ge 2$). Hence (without knowing whether there is an $x$ with $x^2=2$), you can define $L = \{x \in \Bbb{R} \mid x \ge 0, x^2 \le 2\}$ and you know that it is non-empty ($1 \in L$) and bounded above (if $x \in L$, then $x < 2$). But you also know that every non-empty bounded-above set of real numbers has a supremum $s$, say. And then you can prove that $s^2 = 2$. There is no circularity here, even though $s \in L$.

In this case (as pointed out by fleablood in a comment), if you were to change $\le$ in the definition of $L$ to $<$, you would get the same result, but the supremum $s$ would not be a member of $L$. However, there are proofs where you need to reason about a set that must contain a particular number of interest in order to establish what that number is. For example, to prove that any family $F$ of open intervals that covers the closed interval $I = [0, 1]$ has a finite subfamily that covers $I$, you look at the set $M$ of $x \in [0, 1]$ such that a finite subfamily of $F$ covers $[0, x]$ and then prove that $1 \in M$. It would be hard to recast that without allowing $1 \in M$.

Comment: Two things to point out.  Although we find out in the end that $s \in L$ we didn't *know* that at the start of the proof.  And had we written the proof with the set $L' = \{x\in \mathbb R| x\ge 0, x^2<2, x^2 \ne 2\}$ the exact same result occurs as $s'=\sup L'$ will have $s'\not\in L'$ and the whole issue needn't arise.... well, it needn't have arisen anyway but....

Comment: Yes. I did think about mentioning that point and have now updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

We don't know much about real numbers at this stage.  We know that every rational number is a real.  And we know that every set of real numbers that is bounded above will have a least upper bound.  But that's about all. (Okay, we know it's an ordered fields and... more stuff)

We do not know that there actually is any number $r$ so that $r^2 = 2$?  Why *should* there be?  Sure,  *if* there *were* such a number than $r\in L$ but we don't know any number exists.

(Here's an analogy.  Suppose I asked you to prove that something that doesn't exist *does* exist.  Suppose I asked you to prove that there is a smallest positive number $s$.  That is a number $s$ so that $s > 0$ and for any $t>0$ then $s \le t$.  There *is* no such number.  But I'm asking you to prove it.  So you say let $R= \{x| x > 0\}$.  But then you declare that because $s> 0$ then $s \in R$ so what's left to be done.....)

(Or maybe if we defined $S = \{x| 5< x \le \infty\}$ and we argue well if $w = \infty$ then $w \in S$......  Just because the set is defined to *allow* $w = \infty$ doesn't mean that it *does* have it.)

So we don't know that there is an $r$ so that $r^2=2$.

But we do know that $s=\sup L$ exists. (That because $L$ is not empty [$1\in L$] and $L$ is bounded above [If $s\ge 2$ then $s^2 \ge 4>2$ so $s\not \in L$ so $2$ is an upper bound] and the reals have the least upper bound property.)

So how does $s^2$ compare to $2$?  Either $s^2 < 2$ or $s^2 > 2$ or $s^2 = 2$.  If we can prove $s^2 < 2$ and $s^2 > 2$ are both impossible than we'd have to conclude $s^2 \ge 2$ *and* $s^2 \le 2$ and we must conclude $s^2 = 2$

=======

> if $s^2 < 2$ then if we let $\epsilon = \frac {2-s^2}3$.  As $1$ and $1\in L$ we know that $\epsilon \le \frac 13$ so $\epsilon^2 < \epsilon$.  And so $(s+ \epsilon)^2 = s^2 + 2\epsilon + \epsilon^2< s^2 + 3\epsilon =s^2-(2-s^2) = 2$.  So $s < s+\epsilon \in L$ contradicting that $s$ is an upper bound of $L$.

> So $s^2 \ge 2$.

> Do something similar if we assume $s^2 > 2$.  Then let $\delta = \frac{s^2 -2}2$.  As $y \ge 1.5\implies y^2 \ge 2.25$ we know $\delta < 1$ so $\delta^2 < \delta$ and .... same stuff.   $(s-\delta)^2 = s^2 - 2\delta + \delta^2> s^2 -2\delta = s^2 -(s^2-2) = 2$.  (And if $t\ge  (s-\delta)$ then $t^2 \ge (s-\delta)^2 > 2$.) So $s-\delta$ is an upper bound contradicting that $s$ is the *least* upper bound of $L$.

So $s^2 \le 2$.

Well if $s$ exists, and $s^2 \ge 2$ and $s^2 \le 2$ then we must have $s^2 = 2$.

And that's that.

And, yes, $s \in L$.

(Actually the proof would have worked *just* as well if we had defined $L$ as $L = \{x| x\ge 0; x^2 < 2\}$.  ANd just as an aside there was no need to specify $x \ge 0$--- it doesn't matter that negative values are in $L$ because the $\sup$ would still be positive.)

Comment: So essentially, there is no problem defining sets that have elements that I want to show which exist/not exist? ( As long as the set is not empty and there are no paradoxes ).

Comment: And also, as long as the set  is defined with properties already established in my working-environment ( for example If I already learned about natural numbers and there is no restriction to using them in whatever problem I'm working on then I have no problem defining sets composed of natural numbers ).

Comment: "there is no problem defining sets that have elements that I want to show which exist/not exist?"  Sure consider the set $K=\{n \in \mathbb N|n$ is prime$; n \le 10000\}$ that doesn't mean $10000\in K$.  Or consider the set $P= \{x\in R| x^2 \le-42\}$.  That doesn't mean $\sqrt{-42}\in P$.